# template incomplete type used in nested specifier

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I've looked through several on-topic questions but it didn't help, sorry if duplicated.

Why is `Inner` an incomplete type there? Where is the circular dependence?

P.S. `NOT_USED` is a placeholder class to keep specialization partial

```
template <class A>
struct Outer
{
    template <class NOT_USED, class Enabled = void>
    struct Inner
    { static void inner() { std::cout << "not enabled\n"; } };

    template <class NOT_USED>
    struct Inner<NOT_USED, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, A>::value>::type>
    { static void inner() { std::cout << "enabled\n"; } };
};

template <class A>
void call_inner(A& a)
{
    Outer<A>::template Inner<void>::inner(); // #1
}

int main()
{
    int intVar = 10;
    double doubleVar = 1;
    call_inner(intVar); // OK
    call_inner(doubleVar); // Error at #1: incomplete type ‘Outer<double>::Inner<void>’ used in nested name specifier
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I change the second specialization to (`NOT_USED->Type`, `is_same<int, A>` -> `is_same<int, Type>`)

```
template<typename Type>
struct Inner<Type, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, Type>::value>::type>
{ static void inner() { std::cout << "enabled\n"; } };
```

And `call_inner` to (Note `Inner<void>`->`Inner<T>`)

```
template <class T>
void call_inner(T& t)
{
    Outer<T>::template Inner<T>::inner();
}
```

Everything compiles. Why is that? Apparently, the dependence on `Outer` template parameter somehow changes instantiation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible fix:

```
template <class A>
struct Outer
{
    template <class NOT_USED, typename T = A, class Enabled = void>
    struct Inner
    { static void inner() { std::cout << "not enabled\n"; } };

    template <class NOT_USED, typename T>
    struct Inner<NOT_USED, T,
                 typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, T>::value
                                      && std::is_same<A, T>::value>::type>
    { static void inner() { std::cout << "enabled\n"; } };
};
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how and why dependance on `Outer` template parameter changes `Inner`instantiation behaviour?

Comment: `std::is_same<int, A>` is non dependent of `Inner`, whereas `std::is_same<int, T>` is. so in one case you have hard error failure, and in the other case you have a substitution failure (and SF INAE :) ).

Answer (score 0):

The Clang error message is more explicit:

> ```
> ess.cpp:11:52: error: no type named 'type' in
>       'std::__1::enable_if<false, void>'; 'enable_if' cannot be used to disable
>       this declaration
>   ...Inner<NOT_USED, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<int, A>::value>::type>
>                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ess.cpp:18:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'Outer<double>' requested
>       here
>     Outer<A>::template Inner<void>::inner(); // #1
>     ^
> ess.cpp:26:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
>       'call_inner<double>' requested here
>     call_inner(doubleVar); // Error at #1: incomplete type <BF>Outer<dou...
> ```

As you have an `enable_if` that restrict instanciation to A == int, you cannot instantiate `Outer<double>::Inner<void>`.

Comment: Why SFINAE is not applicable here? Please see the updated question, what is the difference in `Inner` instantiation?